# Is using an ANOVA or multiple t-tests the best way to compare monthly and annual data?

Tags: anova, t-test

I have daily precipitation data for two locations over two years. I need to compare them to see if there is an annual difference (combining the two years of data), and if there is a difference in any particular month (a month is also the combination of the two years of data).

Is this best analyzed using a 2 x 12 two-way ANOVA (although N is different for different months), or would a lot of student t-tests be what I need, or both?

Comment: I feel this is hard to answer without getting a feel for your data. We would expect the variance varying with the mean over the different seasons. There is probably autocorrelation in the series. So modelling this would be the way to go; time series and/or mixed models seem a good bet. A paired (paired by day/month) t-test would probably give an acceptable answer as well.

Comment: Thank you Erik, jonsca and Stavros for all of your help! This site is wonderful!!

Answer (score -1):

I would look up "mixed models" if I were you, ANOVA is not the best idea for this kind of data. Good luck!

Comment: This answer is missing a) A reason why ANOVA is not the best idea, b) A reason why mixed model are better and c) any help in finding a reference to them. As such, I don't feel it is a help to the OP.